# Is the UIViewController calling the method presentViewController removed from the memory?

Tags: ios, memory-management, uiviewcontroller, uistoryboard

Supposedly I have a **UIViewController A** and a **UIViewController B**. From A, I call the method presentViewController:B. When B shows up, what happens to A? Is it removed from the memory? If not, what method should I call to delete it?

If my UI flow is like this, **A->B->A->B->A->B->**... and so on, how to prevent the memory from increasing accordingly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you use the `presentViewController:animated:completion:` method from controller `A` to present controller `B` modally, what happens is that the `presentedViewController` property of `A` is set to controller `B`, and the `presentingViewController` property of `B` is set to `A`. Thus, both controllers are kept in memory while the presentation is taking place.

When you go from `B` to `A`, you call `dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:` on `A` via the `presentingViewController` property of `B`, like this:

```
[self.presentingViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

(You can also call `[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil]` and the system will automatically forward the request to the presenting view controller.)

After that, the `presentedViewController` property of `A` will be set to `nil` and, consequently, it will be subject to memory deallocation by the system, provided that there isn't any other strong pointer pointing to it.

Comment: what happens if I have another UIViewController C? So the flow would be like this, A->B->C->A->..
When C calls dismissViewController, isn't it B that shows up?

Comment: @OscarYuandinata If you want to go from `C` to `A`, then call `dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:` on `A`. It will remove `A`'s presented view controller (`B`), and any other child up in the stack of presented view controllers (`C`).

Comment: I just read about assigning UIViewController as rootViewController
eg. <code>self.view.window.rootViewController = confirmPictureViewController;</code>
Which one is the appropriate way to switch UIViewController?

Comment: @OscarYuandinata It depends. Assigning to `rootViewController` embeds the view controller in a navigation hierarchy. Presenting view controllers using `presentViewController:animated:completion:` is more appropriate for temporary screens. For example, imagine an app that wants to upload a file. When the user presses "Upload", a table view controller is presented modally to ask the user which file she wants to upload. Check the HIG: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/MobileHIG.pdf

Comment: rootViewController is what I need then. Anyway, 1 more question. Similar to my original question, is the viewcontroller assigning rootViewController removed from memory?

Comment: @OscarYuandinata One small correction. Assigning to the `rootViewController` property of the window doesn't automatically embed it into a navigation controller. This happens only if `confirmPictureViewController` is a navigation controller. What I meant is that you typically assign a navigation controller as root view controller of your window and then push controllers `A`, `B` and `C` to do the navigation.

Comment: @OscarYuandinata And about memory management, the window holds a strong pointer to its root view controller, so when you assign it to nil it will be deallocated if there is not any other view controller retaining it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48240/discussion-between-oscar-yuandinata-and-daniel-martin)

Answer (score 1):

No, A won't be removed from memory.
And if you want to alternate between A and B you can either:

- use a `UINavigationController` and push B, then pop it off again and you're back at A
- or make B the new root controller of your window and then A again and add a proper transition
- or use a as the root and present B. Then dismiss B and you're back at A.

Answer (score 0):

The `UIViewController` will stay in memory unless you popped it.

Use push & **pop** instead of just pushing new `UIViewControllers`.

Instead of this `A->B->A->B->A->B->`

You'll get this `A<->B`

Answer (score 0):

Have a root view controller when ever **A** completes it's task let your root view  is responsible of removing **A** and and presenting **B**. Like wise when **B** finishes its task alert your root view to remove **B** and show **A** again.

Answer (score 0):

It won't be released automatically. You can release it manually by using `dismissModalViewControllerAnimated`.

Here is a very good tutorial to see this : [Link](http://koolistov.net/blog/2012/02/26/dismissing-modal-view-controller-advice/)